# How to select aggregates with Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I have 2 models: `User` and `Transaction` with `user_id`, `type`, and `amount` fields. I want to be able to select users with array of transactions grouped by type like so:

```
{ // User instance 
    'id': 123,
    'username': 'John'
    'transactions': [
        'type1': '231', // `type`: `sum(amount)`
        'type2': '543'
    ]
}
```

I will select arrays of users so I need this to load eagerly. How should I write an Eloquent model for that? I've read all docs but still don't know how to approach this.

Comment: when you do sum(amount), which transactions takes for sum ?

Comment: Transactions where `transaction.user_id = user.id`, grouped by `user_id` and `type`

Answer (score 1):

You Can try Like :

```
  $column = [DB::raw('SUM(order_qty) as volume'),
            DB::raw('SUM(order_qty*price) as value')];
 $oldValueVolume = OrderProduct::select($column)
                    ->where('order_id', $ordersId)
                    ->first();
```

Comment: What question are you answering? What are those columns?

Answer (score 0):

```
User model:

public function transactions()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Transaction::class, 'user_id');
}
```

So then the call:

```
User::with(
    [
        'transactions' => function ($q) {
            return $q->groupBy(['type', 'user_id'])
                     ->selectRaw('sum(amount) as sum, type, user_id');
        }
    ]
)->get();
```

*Notes*

1. I used 'with' for eager loading.
2. You mentioned a custom structure (pairs) in a question:

This part

```
'transactions': [
    'type1': '231', // `type`: `sum(amount)`
    'type2': '543'
]
```

That's not what Eloquent does by-default, but [you can always remap it](https://adamwathan.me/2016/07/14/customizing-keys-when-mapping-collections/).